# How would I fix this 'if' statement error?

Tags: python, if-statement, input, menu

I'm trying to make a BMI calculator for health class.  I don't have any of the calculations yet, as I'm just testing the menu in the beginning.  for some reason, every time I try to run the code, it shows me an error (shown below the code I have so far).  I'm new to python, so this seems like a rookie mistake.  if you could please help, that would be great.

```
*my code below

    ans = input('''
***The Body Mass Index***
    1. I use Kilograms and Metres
    2. I'M AMERICAN!!!
    ''')
if ans==1
    m = input("Your height in Metres")
    kg = input("Your weight in Kilograms")
if ans==2
    print("Stawp yelling at me!!")
    inc = input("Your height in Inches")
    lbs = input("Your weight in Pounds")
else
    print("please try again with a valid input")
```

the error appears after the first if statement:

```
 if ans==1
```

Comment: You need a colon after your if statement like `if ans==1:`, etc. And for the `else` statement too. Also you have to convert your `input()` to an `int` or else comparing `ans` to one will fail, as that function only will return a string. You have to compare `ans=='1'`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing colons after your if/else statements. Also, [`input()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_input.asp) returns a `string`, not an `int`. Try this:

```
if int(ans)==1:
    m = input("Your height in Metres")
    kg = input("Your weight in Kilograms")
elif int(ans)==2:
    print("Stawp yelling at me!!")
    inc = input("Your height in Inches")
    lbs = input("Your weight in Pounds")
else:
    print("please try again with a valid input")
```

Comment: Yes, got it. Edited now.

Answer (score 0):

You need colons after the if and the else.

Your else will catch ans=1 since it only applies to ==2.

The else should be something like if ans not in range(1..2): or something like that.